# Attaching a created Google Doc from Google Forms through Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to attach a google doc through Apps Script. This doc is being created by Google Forms and is changing. I need this to be emailed to me. Everything is working but adding the attachment and I continue to get a failure email and can't get the code right. Below is the code:

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
var student = e.values[4];
var grade = e.values[5];
var date = e.values[2];
var staff = e.values[6];
var locationOfIncident = e.values[7];
var timeOfIncident = e.values[3];
var othersInvolvedTeachersStaff = e.values[8];
var othersInvolvedStudents = e.values[9];
var othersInvolvedWitnesses = e.values[10];
var explanationOfIncident = e.values[11];
var actionsTakenByStaffPriorToReferral = e.values[12];

var officeDisciplineReferralTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("1X2OL1TjIq4SH92kUN2xhSeyjkAF_OqqBXeGAbgI-7KU");
var responses = DriveApp.getFolderById("12NhsRcegOH_ZFYtMmVoT44pYdBs_NlLL");

var copy = officeDisciplineReferralTemplate.makeCopy(date + ', ' + student, responses);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
var blob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText("<<Student>>", student);
body.replaceText("<<Grade>>", grade);
body.replaceText("<<Date>>", date);
body.replaceText("<<Staff>>", staff);
body.replaceText("<<Location of Incident>>", locationOfIncident);
body.replaceText("<<Time of Incident>>", timeOfIncident);
body.replaceText("<<Teachers/Staff>>", othersInvolvedTeachersStaff);
body.replaceText("<<Student Directly Involved>>", othersInvolvedStudents);
body.replaceText("<<Witnesses>>", othersInvolvedWitnesses);
body.replaceText("<<Explanation of Incident>>", explanationOfIncident);
body.replaceText("<<Actions Taken By Staff Prior to Referral>>", actionsTakenByStaffPriorToReferral);

const file = Utilities.newBlob(doc, 'text/plain', 'OfficeReferral.doc')

var email = MailApp.sendEmail("jscoggins@paden.k12.ok.us", 
'Office Discipline Referral',
'Office Discipline Referral', 
{attachments: [blob]});

doc.saveAndClose();}
```

If someone could please help with the coding for the attachment. I've tried videos and reading other code and can't understand it for what I need.

Comment: Try `var blob = doc.getAs('application/pdf');`

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const template = DriveApp.getFileById(e.values[1]);//pass the file id from the form
  const dest = DriveApp.getFolderById(e.values[2]);//pass the folder id from the form
  let copy = template.makeCopy(new Date() + ', ' + e.values[3], dest);
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  let body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("<<one>>", e.values[1]);
  body.replaceText("<<two>>", e.values[2]);
  body.replaceText("<<three>>", e.values[3]);
  body.replaceText("<<four>>", e.values[4]);
  body.replaceText("<<five>>", e.values[5]);
  body.replaceText("<<six>>", e.values[6]);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  const blob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  MailApp.sendEmail("email address", 'SUBJECT', 'BODY', { attachments: [blob] });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to `const file = Utilities.newBlob(doc, 'text/plain', 'OfficeReferral.doc')`. Because in your script, `doc` is a Class Document object.
- `var blob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');` is the original template document. So, it seems that your updated document is not used. I'm worried that this might be another issue.
- You use `doc.saveAndClose()`. But, this is put into the last line. In the case of your script, it is required to move to just after the line of the last `body.replaceText`.
- `doc.getBlob()` has already been a Blob of the PDF format.
- `MailApp.sendEmail` returns no value.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var student = e.values[4];
  var grade = e.values[5];
  var date = e.values[2];
  var staff = e.values[6];
  var locationOfIncident = e.values[7];
  var timeOfIncident = e.values[3];
  var othersInvolvedTeachersStaff = e.values[8];
  var othersInvolvedStudents = e.values[9];
  var othersInvolvedWitnesses = e.values[10];
  var explanationOfIncident = e.values[11];
  var actionsTakenByStaffPriorToReferral = e.values[12];

  var officeDisciplineReferralTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById("1X2OL1TjIq4SH92kUN2xhSeyjkAF_OqqBXeGAbgI-7KU");
  var responses = DriveApp.getFolderById("12NhsRcegOH_ZFYtMmVoT44pYdBs_NlLL");

  var copy = officeDisciplineReferralTemplate.makeCopy(date + ', ' + student, responses);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("<<Student>>", student);
  body.replaceText("<<Grade>>", grade);
  body.replaceText("<<Date>>", date);
  body.replaceText("<<Staff>>", staff);
  body.replaceText("<<Location of Incident>>", locationOfIncident);
  body.replaceText("<<Time of Incident>>", timeOfIncident);
  body.replaceText("<<Teachers/Staff>>", othersInvolvedTeachersStaff);
  body.replaceText("<<Student Directly Involved>>", othersInvolvedStudents);
  body.replaceText("<<Witnesses>>", othersInvolvedWitnesses);
  body.replaceText("<<Explanation of Incident>>", explanationOfIncident);
  body.replaceText("<<Actions Taken By Staff Prior to Referral>>", actionsTakenByStaffPriorToReferral);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var blob = doc.getBlob();
  MailApp.sendEmail("jscoggins@paden.k12.ok.us", 'Office Discipline Referral', 'Office Discipline Referral', { attachments: [blob] });
}
```